# Why does this loop take 5 seconds to execute in the django server but only 0.8 in the shell?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to figure out a timing discrepancy in my python django project.

When I run the function in the shell, it only takes about a second to get the return object and return it.

When I run it by using an api call the timing says it takes over 5 seconds to loop through and serialize the objects.

Below is the function in question:

```
def serialize_particular(id=-1, all_available=False, page=0, maxOn=40):
    if id != -1:
        b = MyModel.objects.filter(id=id)

        if len(b) == 0:
            return []
        else:
            b = b[0]
        data = []

        if all_available:
            oThings = b.things
        else:
            oThings = b.things_available

        count = len(oThings)
        start = maxOn * page
        end = start + maxOn
        if start > count:
            oThings = oThings.filter(id=-1)
            nextPage = -1
        else:
            if end > count:
                end = count
                page = -2
            oThings = oThings[start:end]
            nextPage = page + 1

        for inv in oThings:
            data.append({})
            data[-1]['id'] = inv.id
            data[-1]['available'] = inv.available
            data[-1]['integer'] = inv.integer
            data[-1]['subObject'] = {}
            data[-1]['subObject']['name'] = inv.subObject.name
            data[-1]['subObject']['category'] = inv.subObject.category
            data[-1]['subObject']['subcategory'] = inv.subObject.subcategory
            data[-1]['subObject']['listOfSubs'] = []
            for subsub in inv.subObject.listOfSubs.all():
                data[-1]['subObject']['listOfSubs'].append({})
                data[-1]['subObject']['listOfSubs'][-1]['name'] = subsub.name
                data[-1]['subObject']['listOfSubs'][-1]['category'] = subsub.category
                data[-1]['subObject']['listOfSubs'][-1]['subcategory'] = subsub.subcategory

        return data, nextPage
```

Below is my timing function that I use in the server:

```
class Timing:

    active = True

    def __init__(self, text):
        if self.active:
            self.text = text
            self.start = time.time()

    def end(self):
        if self.active:
            self.end = time.time()
            self.total = self.end - self.start
            print("[%r] %2.6f s" %(self.text, self.total))
```

Below is the relevant code I use in the server api call:

```
    T = Timing("API.things: Getting MyModel things")
    s = serialize_particular(1, False, 0, 50000)
    data = s[0]
    nextPage = s[1]
    T.end()
```

Below is the output of the timing in the server's log:

```
['API.things: Getting MyModel things'] 5.652001 s
```

Below is the output of my shell:

```
>>> def t(id):
...     T = Timing("API.things: Getting MyModel things")
...     z = api.serialize_business_inventory(id, False, 0, 50000)
...     T.end()
...     return z

>>> s = t(1)
['API.things: Getting MyModel things'] 0.469001 s
```

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Just as an aside, I did try using prefetch. It did not have any effect. The slowdown is in the actual serialization. However, each function call is still slowing down by a factor of 10. I can print out more stats if needed.

Comment: Also as an side, I ended up creating an api call that initializes a request and then another that ensures it's been initialized and will return the data in chunks. Granted it's still slow and this ends up being about 2x as slow as even the first 5s method, however I can start displaying the data to the user immediately.